# Select columns from both lists after filtering

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query currently:

```
    var clientsToPull =
        parameters.Where(x => providers.Select(y => x.ClientGuid).Contains(x.ClientGuid))
            .GroupBy(x => x.ClientGuid)
            .Select(y => new ClientsToPull { ClientGuid = y.Key, StartDate = y.Min(c => c.FromDate)});
```

What this is meant to do is first check the parameters list to make sure that the client guid exists in the providers list. Then it groups the ClientGuids on the parameters list and selects the clientGuid and min StartDate.

The problem I have is that I need to also select some of the columns from the providers list such as a UserName. How exactly would I do this? Is it possible to do this in 1 linq statement, or would I have to do this in 2 separate statements?

```
public class Providers
{
public Guid ClientGuid {get; set;},
public string UserName {get; set;},
public string Password {get; set;}
}

public class Parameters
{
public Guid ClientGuid {get; set;},
public string StartDate {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is there any relation between `ClientGuid` and `UserName`? I mean per user there will be only 1 ClientGuid something like that?

Comment: show us parameters and providers declaration

Comment: you can select it, after the group by it is already filtered.

Comment: 1 clientGuid to many UserName/PWs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one statement, using a `Join` to match your `parameters` with `providers` and project information from both. e.g...

```
var providers = new List<Providers>()
{
    new Providers() { ClientGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "A", Password = "B" },
    new Providers() { ClientGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "B", Password = "C" },
};

var parameters = new List<Parameters>()
{
    new Parameters() { ClientGuid = providers.First().ClientGuid, StartDate = "C" },
    new Parameters() { ClientGuid = providers.First().ClientGuid, StartDate = "B" },
    new Parameters() { ClientGuid = providers.Take(2).Last().ClientGuid, StartDate = "Tomorrow!" },
    new Parameters() { ClientGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), StartDate = "Last year" },
};

var result = parameters
    .GroupBy(a => a.ClientGuid, a => a)
    .Join(
        providers,
        parameterGroup => parameterGroup.Key,
        provider => provider.ClientGuid,
        (parameterGroup, provider) => new { provider.ClientGuid, provider.UserName, MinStartDate = parameterGroup.Min(groupMember => groupMember.StartDate) });
```